# Magento 2 checkout: how to make vat number required

Tags: magento2, checkout, vat

How can I make the vat tax required in the Magento-2 checkout? From the panel, I can set it as default only in the "create new account" form.

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve via create [plugin](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/extension-dev-guide/plugins.html) of class `\Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessor`

On  after method of  function process(), add required field to vat id field

### PLugin class

```
<?php
namespace {Vendorname}\{Module}\Plugin\Block\Magento\Checkout;


class LayoutProcessorPlugin
{
    public function afterProcess(
        \Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessor $subject,
        array  $jsLayout
    )
    {

        if(isset(
            $jsLayout['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['shipping-step']
            ['children']['shippingAddress']['children']['shipping-address-fieldset']['children']['vat_id']
        )){
            $jsLayout['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['shipping-step']
            ['children']['shippingAddress']['children']['shipping-address-fieldset']['children']['vat_id']
            ['validation'] =[
                'required-entry' => true,
            ];
        }


        $configuration = $jsLayout['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['billing-step']['children']['payment']['children']['payments-list']['children'];
        foreach ($configuration as $paymentGroup => $groupConfig) {
            if (isset($groupConfig['component']) AND $groupConfig['component'] === 'Magento_Checkout/js/view/billing-address') {



                if(isset(
                    $jsLayout['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['billing-step']['children']
                    ['payment']['children']['payments-list']['children'][$paymentGroup]['children']['form-fields']
                    ['children']['vat_id']
                )){
                    $jsLayout['components']['checkout']['children']['steps']['children']['billing-step']['children']
                    ['payment']['children']['payments-list']['children'][$paymentGroup]['children']['form-fields']
                    ['children']['vat_id'] ['validation'] =[
                        'required-entry' => true,
                    ];
                }

            }
        }

        return $jsLayout;
    }

}
```

### Define di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?> 
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\LayoutProcessor" >
        <plugin name="add_required_field_to_vat_id" sortOrder="1"
                type="{Vendorname}\{Module}\Plugin\Block\Magento\Checkout\LayoutProcessorPlugin"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

Comment: i have to save it as {Vendorname}\{Module}\Plugin\Block\Magento\Checkout\LayoutProcessorPlugin.php?

Comment: sorry man it do not work

Answer (score 0):

Run below SQL query

```
UPDATE `eav_attribute` SET `is_required` = '1' WHERE `eav_attribute`.`attribute_id` = 36;
```

[image]

Comment: I would prefer something like: UPDATE eav_attribute SET is_require = '1' WHERE attribute_code='vat_id';

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE eav_attribute SET is_required = '1'
WHERE eav_attribute.attribute_code = 'vat_id'
  AND entity_type_id = 2;
```