# vat number required in Magento-2 checkout

Tags: magento2, magento-2.2.1

I enabled the `vat field` from admin panel and now i want to make it **required** during checkout shipping step.

I have followed the steps described [here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/220922/magento-2-checkout-how-to-make-vat-number-required) but it is not working.
What is missing from the steps of the above link? Can you suggest how to solve this?

Thanks in advance

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This can be enabled via admin panel:

```
Stores > Configuration > Customer Configuration > Name and Address Options > Show Tax/VAT Number
```

The **possible** options are:

- No
- Optional
- Required

[image]

On **checkout**

[image]

Now, other possibilities are :

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kNdch.png)
If you navigate to:

> Stores > Configuration > Customers > Customer Configuration > (Change
>   Scope to correct website/store view) > Create New Account Options >
>   Show VAT Number on Storefront
>
> Change dropdown to Yes.

You'll then have to set up your tax classes/tax rules/customer groups and then in the above section you can assign the correct values to the groups.

[image]

http://docs.magento.com/m2/ce/user_guide/tax/vat-validation-configure.html

[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zDupa.png) From **Database**

```
UPDATE `eav_attribute` SET `is_required` = '1' WHERE `eav_attribute`.`attribute_id` = 36;
```

[image: it's working]

Comment: Yes ,  i have enabled from admin panel ( as a required option) but when i do checkout steps the field is not required on front end. User can complete checkout without without filling vat number.

Comment: And once you add your VAT in customer account then there no need to ask on checkout again, but if there's not added VAT then it will compulsory ask for VAT.

Comment: Yes but in the case when user/customer is not logged in , when he complete checkout the VAT Number is not required (i have updated my question with a screenshot)

Comment: Okay let me generate it

Comment: Hi, Check my answer !

Comment: Yes, it is working now. Thank you very much :)

Comment: Does it work for guest users also? Because if a guest user enters vat number, then his vat should be exempted from total.